# Trying to Insert blank rows x number of times, x = cell value

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to insert a specific number of blank rows, which is based on a value in a cell. This value in the cell is a count function from a table.

I have an "Import Table" sheet which contains all my data. Next to the table I have a couple count functions, which count general categories coming from the table. For example on the "Import Table" worksheet Cell J8(Domestic Equity), Cell J9 has the count function which for this case comes to "11". I now want 11 rows to be inserted at a specific spot in my "Analysis" worksheet. In this worksheet there are heading also names like the count headings(domestic equity).
So under domestic equity I want the rows to be insert. In the analysis sheet a function is already created in the first row under domestic equity, so the new blank rows have to be inserted under that value in this case under row 6.

The formula already existing in cells (A6,B6,C6,D6,E6) then have to be flash filled into the newly created white rows.

I attached 2 images to hopefully clear up my questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Range("A1").Resize(11, 1).Insert (xlShiftDown)
```

OR

```
Rows(1).Resize(11, 1).Insert (xlShiftDown)
```